# C# - How to initialize complex property when creating new object?

Tags: c#

Say I have an Employee class and one of its properties is of type Department.  In my GUI, I want to create a new Employee and I instantiate it.  I have a collection displayed through a ComboBox of Department objects, so that the end-user can select (assign) a Department for each Employee.

My question is, say when I instantiate this Employee class and I want to default the Department to some value, say "Finance" which is for the Department.Code property.

How can I do this?

I tried but doesn't seem to like when saving:

```
this.Employee = Employee.CreateEmployee("-1", DateTime.Now, "Active", ...);
this.Employee.Department= new Department { Code = "Finance" };
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What saving are you talking about? Also what it doesn't like? Are you getting an exception, a not desired result? In the first case post the exception stack trace, in the second case explain the desired result first and then the undesired.

Comment: Does the code compile? Does it run? What does it do? What did you expect or want it to do?

Comment: if that's cut & paste from your solution, I'm guessing it won't even compile since you don't have your parens for your Department constructor call (should be: = new Department() blah blah)

Comment: @AllenG - you don't need them with object initializer syntax... go give it a try with `var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };`

Comment: @Russ Cam - hmmm... it's been a while since I've tried it, but I thought my compiler kept giving me errors when I tried that.  That could just be mis-remembering on my part, though.

Comment: @AllenG - just noticed Darin's link to the msdn article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally classes are built with constructors; ie

```
public class Department
{
    string _code = "";
    public Department() {}
    public Department(string code) {
        _code = code;
    }
}
```

So that when your program creates a new department object, you can do:

```
Department finance = new Department("Finance");
this.Employee = Employee.CreateEmployee("-1", DateTime.Now, "Active", ...);
this.Employee.Department= finance;
```

Edit: You'd probably be better off using enumerators for this, such that you can declare an enumerator:

```
public enum Departments
{
    Finance,
    Technology,
    Sales
}
public class Employee
{
    Departments _employeeDepartment;
    public Employee() {}
    public Employee(Department EmployeeDepartment)
    {
        _employeeDepartment = EmployeeDepartment;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not generally, classes are always instantiated with constructors. What the OP showed is object initialization syntax supported in C# since 3.0. Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: Ah, I thought that was just a typo.